# ORA-24033 : No recipient for message has been detected

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, deadlock

I am using Oracle E-business Suite R12.1, 11G database version.

Error I encountered when trying to create or modify a user or responsibility:

> ORA-24033 : no recipient for message has been detected in
>   FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_API.UPDATE_ASSIGNMENT

#### My workaround

I have followed Oracle metalink doc (Doc ID 358151.1) to fix the error.  Whenever I try to do the first step (dropping the existing subscriber), it gives this error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object
>   30x0C2ABE5980x0C798B3F80x0D9CA49D8
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS", line 7541
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 441
>   ORA-06512: at line 5

I have to fix ORA-04020 so I can later recreate the existing subscriber (by dropping the the existing one, then adding a new one).

1. I tried to bounce the applications and the database.
2. I compiled the apps schema.
3. I tried to find out where is the lock and which schema is blocking the other so I can kill that session:

   ```
   sql> SELECT
    c.owner,
    c.object_name,
    c.object_type,
    b.SID,
    b.serial#,
    b.status,
    b.osuser,
    b.machine
   ```

   FROM
        v$locked_object a ,
        v$session b,
        dba_objects c
     WHERE
        b.SID = a.session_id
     AND
        a.object_id = c.object_id;

   **Output:**

   ```
    OWNER    OBJECT_NAME         OBJECT_TYPE  SID       SERIAL#     STATUS
   -----   -------------         ----------   ------    -------    -----------
       APPLSYS  FND_CONCURRENT_QUEUES    TABLE     152       3                INACTIVE
       APPLSYS  FND_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS  TABLE     466       7                INACTIVE
   ```

   Then tried to find out which session is blocking the other to kill it:

   ```
   sql>SELECT l1.SID  ||' IS BLOCKING '|| l2.SID
   FROM v$lock l1, v$lock l2
   WHERE l1.BLOCK =1 AND l2.request > 0
   AND l1.id1=l2.id1
   AND l1.id2=l2.id2;
   ```

   But I got no returned rows.

Some of the suggestions on the Internet state that a deadlock occurs when there are invalid objects in the database. So, I recompiled the invalid objects by running `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql`

That script returned an output. The following is a part of the output:

> ERROR at line 1:
>       ORA-04063: package body "SYS.UTL_RECOMP" has errors
>       ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.UTL_RECOMP"
>       ORA-06512: at line 4

and this was part of the output also:

> ```
> OBJECTS WITH ERRORS  
> -------------------  
>                   1
> ```

Note: I am facing this issue after applying a patch. And it's been over 5 days since the deadlock was detected, even though most of the suggestions regarding to the deadlock says that oracle will manage the release itself. Explicit release not required.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write the solution here for those who might encounter such error in the future.

I solved the error by re-compiling invalid objects.